# AV.link dongle (SCART's CEC)

Tags: converter, protocol, tv

I am looking for a device I can plug into an old TV's [SCART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCART) port, which will feed me remote control commands (like 'arrow-up', 'OK', 'menu', etc.) received over the SCART connector's [AV.link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AV.link) (control bus) pin in a usable way.

By "in a usable way" I mean in a form that is usable by a computer, e.g. over a USB serial connection, or may even as key presses of a virtual USB keyboard; Anything that a common computer could process.

Now, I am not looking for any product purchase advice, but I don't know what to search for on the internet to dig up something like this.
If such a device does not exist, how would I best go about creating one? Using an Arduino, e.g.? A few pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Bus Pirate](https://buspirate.com/) is a general-purpose bus snooping device; while I've not used it myself, it looks like either you'll be able to get it to do what you want with the stock firmware or write your own firmware to handle AV.link and send it up over USB serial.